# Nvidia X Server settings is displaying blank window on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-settings

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on rog zephyrus g14, and when I try to open nvidia x server settings, it only shows blank window. I also tried to run `nvidia-smi` but it only returned this: `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.` I've checked if I have propietary driver selected in additional drivers manager and `nvidia-driver-440` was selected. Any help is appreciated.